# Pullback of a constant coefficient form

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra

Let $\omega=\sum_{I}C_Idx_I$, where $I=(i_1,\dots,i_n)$ is a multi-index and $C_I$ constants, be an $n$-form in $\mathbb{R}^m$, with constant coefficients. Here $dx_I$ means $dx_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{i_2}$.

**Question:** Is there a continuous and injective map $f=(f_1,\dots,f_m):\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ such that the pullback of this form under this map $f^*\omega=\sum_{I}C_Idf_I$ equals $K dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$, where $K$ constant? If yes what if I want my map to be linear and injective? (Here again $df_I=df_{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge df_{i_n})$.

If the answer is no to both questions is there some additional assumption on the form that would make those true?

Comment: So each $C_I\in \mathbb{R}^m$? So this is a vector valued $n$-form? Is $K\in\mathbb{R}^m$ as well then?

Comment: No the $C_I$ are constants as is $K$.

Comment: what do you mean by "$n$-form with constant coefficients in $\mathbb{R}^m$ then? To me that means $\omega$ takes $n$ vectors then spits out a result in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^m$ is the space where the form lives. For example I can consider $dx\wedge dy$ as a 2-form in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In both cases it takes vectors (2-vectors or 3-vectors respectively) and spits out a number. The $n$ refers to how many vectors it takes.

Comment: This seems like just a change of basis in $\Lambda^n(\mathbb{R}^m)$, which is after all a vector space of dimension ${m \choose n}$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @aschepler Yes I agree with that. But which changes of basis can be taken as the pullback of such a map? Is it true that every change of basis in $\Lambda^n(\mathbb{R}^m)$ is the pullback of a map from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: @MadMax if it’s a linear isomorphism I want to say yes. We get an induced representation of the action of $GL(\mathbb{R}^m)$ on the space of $n$ forms on $\mathbb{R}^m$, so any change of basis of $\Lambda^n(\mathbb{R}^m)$ should correspond to a similar action on $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. I am not sure I understand what you mean. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @MadMax any element of $GL(\mathbb{R}^m)$ is a linear isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, and thus a change of basis. From there, there are then induced actions on various spaces constructed from $\mathbb{R}^m$, one of which is $\Lambda^n(\mathbb{R}^m)$, this induced action is also a change of basis since the group is still $GL$. I now realize that this doesn't answer your question completely, as I am not completely sure the induced action  gives every change of basis for $\Lambda^n(\mathbb{R}^m )$.

Comment: Yes. You just want to eliminate the variables $x^{n+1}, \dots, x^m$. The map $f(x^1,\dots, x^m) = (x^1, \dots, x^n, 0, \dots)$ works. I'll let you try to figure out which linear maps also work.

Comment: @Deane except this functions maps $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, so it pulls back forms on $\matbb{R}^n$ not on $\mathbb{R}^m$ where $\omega$ is defined.

Comment: @Deane That map is not injective.

Comment: Sorry. I didn’t see the word injective. It’s not hard to show the answer is yes if $f$ is linear.

Comment: @Deane The map you gave on your last comment is already linear. You mean a different one which is both linear and injective?

Comment: Yes. That’s right

Comment: @Deane If we treat the entries of the matrix of the linear map as variables then the equation $\sum_I C_I df_I= K dx_1\wedge \dots \wedge dx_n$ is basically a system of $\binom{m}{n}$ equations with $m^2$ variables. Since $\binom{m}{n}>m^2$ for large enough $m$  it seems to me hard to find such a linear map. Could you maybe give a hint?

Comment: I keep messing up. My latest answer is that it depends on which differential form it is. Note that if $f$ Is linear and injective, it is bijective. Second, find a form that cannot be written as $dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^n$. The easiest case, I believe, is $n=2$ and $m=4$.

Comment: @MadMax it should be $mn$ variables, and when $m$ choose $n$ is greater than $mn$ you do not have the guarantee that such a map exists. It could work out by happenstance if the extra equations turn out to be dependent one the rest, but I can’t prove that’s always the case.

Comment: @Deane Yes I expected that it would not work with linear maps. Do you think it is possible to do it using a continuous and injective map though?

Comment: @MadMax if the map isn’t linear the pull back of the form isn’t going to have a constant out front unless the $C_I$ is a multi index of $C^\infty$ functions, which just so happen to be the inverse of $df_I$, which is certainly not guaranteed. Look at $m=6$ and $n=3$, you will see that there is no guarantee such a pullback exists.